# Error when registering a custom user in Django

Tags: django

When I want to register a new user in Django, I get the following warning:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: polls_usuario.matriculaUsuario
```

When I edit the registry, both by admin and in the main view, this error does not occur. This error only occurs when creating a new user. When I create a user by the view register, the user is created, with the default enrollment. When I try to create by admin, the user is not even created. What could be happening?

views.py

```
def registrar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        usuario_form = UsuarioForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and usuario_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.usuario.matriculaUsuario = form.cleaned_data.get('matriculaUsuario')
            usuario_form.save()
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request,user)
            return render(request, 'polls/index.html', user)
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/')) 
            #return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
        usuario_form = UsuarioForm()
    return render(request, 'polls/registrar.html', {'form': form , 'usuario_form':usuario_form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class UsuarioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ('matriculaUsuario',)

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Primeiro Nome',max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Opcional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Último Nome',max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Opcional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail',max_length=254, help_text='Informe o seu e-mail (Requerido)')   
    username = forms.CharField(label='Nome de usuário', min_length=4, max_length=150)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Senha', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirmação da senha', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    matriculaUsuario = forms.CharField(label='Matrícula',max_length=12,validators=[ validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[0-9]{12}$'), _('Digite uma matrícula válida'), _('invalid'))])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name','username','matriculaUsuario','email','password1', 'password2',] 
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username'].lower()
        r = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if r.count():
            raise  ValidationError("Nome de usuário já cadastrado")
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
        r = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if r.count():
            raise  ValidationError("E-mail já cadastrado")
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Senhas não conferem")

        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            self.cleaned_data['username'],
            self.cleaned_data['email'],
            self.cleaned_data['password1']
        )
        return user
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Nome')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Sobrenome')
    username = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=150,help_text=("Insira um novo nome de usuário"), label='Nome de usuário')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail')
    matriculaUsuario = forms.CharField(label='Matrícula', max_length=12,validators=[ validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[0-9]{12}$'), _('Digite uma matrícula válida'), _('invalid'))])
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name','username','matriculaUsuario','email']
```

**models.py**

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    matriculaUsuario = models.CharField(default='000000000000',max_length=12,primary_key=True,null=False,help_text=_('São requeridos os 12 dígitos referentes à sua matrícula'), validators=[ validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[0-9]{12}$'), _('Digite uma matrícula válida'), _('invalid'))])
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_usuario(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Usuario.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.usuario.save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_usuario(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Usuario.objects.create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_user_usuario,sender=User)
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_usuario(sender, instance, created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.usuario.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your models.py you set the matriculaUsuario as primary_key:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    matriculaUsuario = models.CharField(default='000000000000',max_length=12,primary_key=True,null=False,help_text=_('São requeridos os 12 dígitos referentes à sua matrícula'), validators=[ validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[0-9]{12}$'), _('Digite uma matrícula válida'), _('invalid'))]) # you set this as primary key
```

You also set a default='000000000000' for it. This is bad because when you are creating a new user and the form is saved the field is getting the same value ('000000000000') every time. This is not possible since you set primary_key=True. Primary key is the unique identifier for the object so it should be unique.

*primary_key=True implies null=False and unique=True. Only one primary key is allowed on an object.*

reference: https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.x/ref/models/fields.html

Consider using an AutoField which will auto-increment the pk upon object creation:

```
matriculaUsuario = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Or another good option is UUIDField which is good for the long term, larger database, as well as making the object's pk hard to guess by attackers.

```
matriculaUsuario = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Also, I don't think you should allow users to edit their matricualUsuario in the EditProfile form as this will create problems.

Comment: thanks, but when I just removed the primary_key, this error appeared: no such column: polls_user.id. I just want that the registration is the form of user authentication, it does not have to be primary_key. How do I do?

Comment: Update matriculaUsuario = models.CharField(default="000000000000",unique=True,max_length=12,null=False,help_text=_('São requeridos os 12 dígitos referentes à sua matrícula'), validators=[ validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[0-9]{12}$'), _('Digite uma matrícula válida'), _('invalid'))])

Comment: @MurilodeJesus - You are getting that error because you already made your migrations and migrated them to the database, thereby creating the columns. I think your best option at this point is to drop your database, delete your migrations, remake your migrations, recreate your database, and then migrate again. However, before you do this you should make sure you have your models generally the way you want them. What is the point of matriculaUsuario? Django automatically generates an auto incremented id for each object if you don't specify a primary_key field.

Comment: @MurilodeJesus - What exactly are you trying to achieve with matriculaUsuario? If you explain that to me I can help you better.

Comment: I'm trying to save in matriculaUsuario the number registration of the student in the system. The problem is in assigning it as unique = True. When I remove unique = True, the error occurs in the user_polys_user_id. Even with a new database, the error occurs.

Comment: @MurilodeJesus - Please post the error traceback and update how you have your code in the question.

Comment: @MurilodeJesus - Also, don't you want it to be unique if it's the student registration number?

Comment: yes, it's necessary. But I created a new project and it works fine. Thanks